# Pure JavaScript to Capture Link Click Data

Tags: javascript, dom

I need help creating a pure JavaScript event listener that captures all clicks on a page, gets the link text/URL, find the logical parent DIV of that link and concatenate the values together.  Take this example code:

```
<body>
    <div class="heading grid-12">
       <!-- Header and navigation links -->
        <a href="index.html">Summer Promotion</a>
    </div>
    <div class="responsiveGrid">
       <!-- page body -->
        <a href="/cart/sweaters/navy.html?promocode=123"><img alt="Navy Sweater" src="nsweater.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer grid-12">
       <!-- Footer and bottom nav links -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showOverlay">About Us</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the above example, I want to capture where the link logically sits on the page, either header|body|footer based on whether the link is a child of these three top level DIVs.   Next, I want to capture the link text from anchor/JavaScript links or the Alt Text from image links.  Finally I want to get the path of the link – excluding the protocol, domain and query strings if an anchor link or converted to a static string “Overlay” if the href is ‘# ‘or ‘javascript:void(0);’.  Using the code above, I’d want the final concatenated string sent to console.log when any link is clicked:

```
'header|Summer Promotion|index.html'
'body|Navy Sweater|/cart/sweaters/navy.html'
'footer|About Us|Overlay'
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What you did so far though?

Comment: I know how to create a listener, get the path via location.pathname and I know how to stitch the values together once found using join.  What I'm clueless about is how to traverse through the DOM to find which of the three parents the link belongs to and how best to code a for loop to tie the link text/alt image.